# Special char bracket in Middlemanapp's haml classname

Tags: javascript, html, haml, handlebars.js, middleman

I am using Middleman App and Handlebars and need `%li.name.s{{status}}` to be parsed to something like `%li.name.s0`, `%li.name.s1`.. based on a model in javascript. This gave me error:

```
%script{:type => "text/html", :id => "item"}
  {{#items}}
  %li.s{{status}}
    %a{href: "#"} {{name}}
  {{/items}}
```

Here is the error:

```
SyntaxError at /test.html
test.haml:217: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC ...lass"=>"name s"}, nil, {status})}>\n <a#{_hamlout.adj... ... ^

Ruby    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb: in class_eval, line 233
Web GET localhost/show.html
```

I guess you can't have brackets in classname. Is there a workaround for this to make Middleman app to ignore? I rather not code in HTML in those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is this `%li.name{class: "s{{status}}"}`

This would avoid using classname directly